# composer install/update failed

Tags: php, laravel, memory, composer-php

Anyone has experience with this error:

```
[301.7MB/151.72s] The following exception is caused by a lack of memory or swap, or not having swap configured
[301.7MB/151.72s] Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#proc-open-fork-failed-errors for details


Warning: proc_open(): fork failed - Cannot allocate memory in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php on line 979

  [ErrorException]
  proc_open(): fork failed - Cannot allocate memory
```

I already set the memory limit to 768M to 1024M and have swap more than enough around 4GB but still experience this problem.

```
free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           4184        1877         823         177        1482        1808
Swap:          5023         596        4427
```

.

```
php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit').PHP_EOL;"
768M
```

Or even set the memory limit manually:

```
php -d extension=phar.so -d extension=xmlwriter.so -dmemory_limit=1024M /usr/local/bin/composer.phar --profile -vvv update
```

Comment: Did you solve your issue? @Frank

Comment: that was a problem with multi php configuration on cloudlinux